# Connect to SQL Server 2008 from PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Using the PHP drivers from Microsoft, we cannot connect using either Windows Authentication or   SQL Server authentication. We use the following PHP code:

```
$serverName =  "(A\B)";
$connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>"u1",
                         "PWD"=>"p1",
                         "Database"=>"db1"); 

$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

Comment: What does "cannot connect" mean? Do you get an error message? If so, could you share it?

Comment: Make sure $serverName is correct... but do seriously consider PHP ADODB... it'll save you a LOT of tears.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell the php sql server stuff is terrible.

The only reliable solution (and I am forced to use SQL Server 2008 here for a very complex project) is using PHP ADODB.

Comment: I use SQL Server 2012 with PDO. Works great, no monolithic ADODB needed.

Comment: PDO fails to execute Stored Procs reliably... hence I reverted to PHP ADODB... but yeh I agree about the monolithic bit :)

Comment: Ahh, in that case, I'm probably going to run into issues pretty soon...perhaps its time to download ADODB.

Comment: They do 'kind of' work... but 2 or 3 times out of 20 calls it just did't work no errors... but if you do continue with PDO and don't have trouble I'll be happy to hear! It is well and also not so well documented that PHP is crap with SQL Server... and sadly PHP ADODB has usually been the only reliable lib for it. Some serious work needs to be put in to stabilise native SQL Server handling.